# Node JS select from MySQL filter array column by array object

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I have a column whose contents can null, a single integer, or several integers separated by a comma. I want to search for specific rows by using my column to filter out unwanted data. Instead of a search string, I have an array that can have a single element or several, How can I work out on this? Am using Node JS + MySQL.
The solution below only works when the column data is a single integer. How can I make it work when the column contains several integers too?

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM `vw_tenants` WHERE units is not null AND property_code =? AND (floors_comunn IN (?);", [property_code, floors], (err, data) => {
connection.release();
if(err) {
    logger.error(err);
    result(null);
} else {
    result(data);
}
```

});

The "**floors**" variable can be `[1]` or have several elements ie `[0,1,3,5,..n]`
The "**floors_comunn**" table column can contain null, single integer ie `3`, or a group of integers separated by a comma ie `2,4,5`

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not clear to me :( .
But I can say one thing, you have to change the database design. It is not good practice to store multiple values in a single field. It should be atomic. This is the very first normal form (1NF)
[Normal forms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/first-normal-form-1nf/)

In DBMS there are many normal forms. It is always good practice to use at least upto 3rd normal form or BCNF.

Comment: I was not aware of this but I had already changed the structure of the table. That was the only solution I could work with. Thanks, your information is helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL also supports JSON Objects now. You can use JSON functions of mysql to search your columns for specific values.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html